# How can we have Request-Reponse times tracked in Tomcat server? - Crashes Occasionally

Tags: java, tomcat, server

I had used the Access logs in server.xml but i need to know how to track each Request-Response timings on each request flowing to tomcat  ?

The reason being is that Tomcat server crashes  **occasionally**  and not able to find the route cause on the same.

I am happy if i can use a Tool to monitor on the same and say upfront that server would be crashing ?.

I am using Tomcat 6. Java 7.
Using Direct DB connection and not in a pool. (This may be a reason - if so please explain on the same how ? )

Please let me know if other details required.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that Tomcat "crashes"? How will obtaining response-times help? Have you looked at the AccessLogValve? It can be configured to log the data you are requesting.

Comment: Why not create a new question on your problem with Tomcat crashing? Presumably you get stack traces, right? If you solve that then doesn't this question become irrelevant? Perhaps I am misunderstanding the situation, but it seems to me that you need to be focusing the underlying problem rather than implementing a diagnostic that may not help at all.

Comment: Hi Skomisa Thanks for your reply. i had gone throughstack traces which dint help me and says memory issue . but my question is that if we have something to track on Request-reponses which all flowing into tomcat container (may be generic way) so that i can handle such request responses and have a fix on the same in code

Comment: HI  Christopher Schultz - Accesslogs didnt provide me much information on the same. If i get Request-Responses times for each method call then i can know which is burdening the Tomcat container and i can have a code fix on the same for better performance.

Comment: @MuraliGowda OK, but even if you obtain the response statistics I still don't understand how that helps you resolve the issue. It may give you response times, but how is that useful if you have memory problems? There is no direct correlation between response time and memory usage. And is there any reason for not using a connection pool for database access? I'd also suggest creating another second question for your Tomcat crash with a stack trace - others might see something there that you did not. (Also, please always prefix the user ID with an **@** in your comments so that we get prompted.)

Comment: Stability (not crashing) and performance are two different issues. I recommend solving one before the other. It doesn't matter how fast you crash if you are crashing ;)

Comment: @skomisa the Rquest respose would help me to refactor the code as the code written was years before and we can atleast make sure server wont be burdened.

Comment: @Christopher Schultz sure pls i got your concerns.  If you are aware of can you  please suggest a tool which can track the server activities ?